# AWK associative array

Tags: awk, mapping, associative-array

Suppose I have 2 files

File-1 map.txt

```
1 tony
2 sean
3 jerry
4 ada
```

File-2 relation.txt

```
tony sean
jerry ada
ada sean
```

Expected-Output result.txt

```
1 2
3 4
4 2
```

My code was:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{map[$1]=$2;next;} {$1=map[$1]; $2=map[$2]; print $0}' map.txt relation.txt > output.txt
```

But I got the left column only:

```
1
3
4
```

It seems that something wrong near `$2=map[$2]`.

Very appreciated if you could help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got the mapping creation the wrong way around, it needs to be:

```
map[$2] = $1
```

Your current script maps numbers to names whereas what you seem to be after is a map from names to numbers.

The following transcript shows the corrected script:

```
pax> cat m.txt
1 tony
2 sean
3 jerry
4 ada

pax> cat r.txt
tony sean
jerry ada
ada sean

pax> awk 'FNR==NR{map[$2]=$1;next;}{$1=map[$1];$2=map[$2];print $0}' m.txt r.txt
1 2
3 4
4 2
```

Comment: Many thanks paxdiablo. I found that if I change name to number, it happened again. for example: 
m.txt:
1 23478267
2 97872632
3 47653728
4 12676782

r.txt:
23478267 97872632
47653728 12676782
12676782 97872632

results.txt was:
1
3
4

Comment: I was trying to map user id (really big number) to smaller integers like 1 2 3 4 5

Answer (score 3):

Using awk.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{map[$2]=$1;next;}{print map[$1], map[$2]}' m.txt r.txt
```